# LNK2005 and LNK1169 error appeared suddenly

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

Please read this carefully before marking as a already answered, because none of the other solutions help with me.

So i'm getting 2 errors when i'm compiling my program in either debug or release:

```
moc_guiitemlistrepeat.obj:-1: error: LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl GUIItemListRepeat::isUpdated(void)" (?isUpdated@GUIItemListRepeat@@QEAAXXZ) already defined in guiitemlistrepeat.obj
```

[image]

```
release\Calendar.exe:-1: error: LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

[image]

They suddenly showed up while i was debugging, and I have no idea what is wrong, because as far as i know i didn't edited that file.

header:

```
#ifndef GUIITEMLISTREPEAT_H
#define GUIITEMLISTREPEAT_H

#include <QtWidgets>
#include "appointmentrepeat.h"

class GUIItemListRepeat : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    GUIItemListRepeat(AppointmentRepeat *appointment);
    ~GUIItemListRepeat();
    AppointmentRepeat* getItem();
signals:
    void isUpdated();
    void showDetails(AppointmentRepeat *todo);
    void remove(GUIItemListRepeat *item);
private slots:
    void showClicked();
    void deleteClicked();
private:
    AppointmentRepeat *m_repeat;
    QLabel *m_title, *m_type, *m_begin, *m_end;
    QPushButton *m_show, *m_delete;
};

#endif // GUIITEMLISTREPEAT_H
```

Source:

```
#include "guiitemlistrepeat.h"

GUIItemListRepeat::GUIItemListRepeat(AppointmentRepeat *appointment)
{
    m_repeat = appointment;

    connect(appointment, SIGNAL(updated()), this, SLOT(isUpdated()));

    m_title = new QLabel(m_repeat->getTitle());
    m_begin = new QLabel(m_repeat->getStart().toString(QString("hh:mm")));
    m_end = new QLabel(m_repeat->getEnd().toString(QString("hh:mm")));
    m_show = new QPushButton(QString("Show"));
    m_delete = new QPushButton(QString("Delete"));

    QString type;
    if (m_repeat->getType() == DAILY)
        type = tr("Dagelijks");
    else if (m_repeat->getType() == WEEKLY)
        type = tr("Wekelijks(%1)").arg(m_repeat->getDate().toString(tr("ddd")));
    else if (m_repeat->getType() == MONTHLY)
        type = tr("Maandelijks(%1)").arg(m_repeat->getDate().toString(tr("dd")));
    else
        type = tr("Jaarlijks(%1)").arg(m_repeat->getDate().toString(tr("dd/MM")));

    m_type = new QLabel(type);

    connect(m_show, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(showClicked()));
    connect(m_delete, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(deleteClicked()));

    QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_type, 0, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_begin, 1, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_end, 2, 0);
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_title, 0, 1, 1, 2);
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_show, 1, 1);
    mainLayout->addWidget(m_delete, 1, 2);
    setLayout(mainLayout);

    setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);

    setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Preferred, QSizePolicy::Fixed);
}

GUIItemListRepeat::~GUIItemListRepeat()
{
    delete m_title;
    delete m_type;
    delete m_begin;
    delete m_end;
    delete m_show;
    delete m_delete;
}

AppointmentRepeat* GUIItemListRepeat::getItem()
{
    return m_repeat;
}

void GUIItemListRepeat::showClicked()
{
    emit showDetails(m_repeat);
}

void GUIItemListRepeat::deleteClicked()
{
    emit remove(this);
}

void GUIItemListRepeat::isUpdated()
{
    m_title->setText(m_repeat->getTitle());
    m_begin->setText(m_repeat->getStart().toString(QString("hh:mm")));
    m_end->setText(m_repeat->getEnd().toString(QString("hh:mm")));

    if (m_repeat->getType() == DAILY)
        m_type->setText(tr("Dagelijks"));
    else if (m_repeat->getType() == WEEKLY)
        m_type->setText(tr("Wekelijks(%1)").arg(m_repeat->getDate().toString(tr("ddd"))));
    else if (m_repeat->getType() == MONTHLY)
        m_type->setText(tr("Maandelijks(%1)").arg(m_repeat->getDate().toString(tr("dd"))));
    else
        m_type->setText(tr("Jaarlijks(%1)").arg(m_repeat->getDate().toString(tr("dd/MM"))));
}
```

It would help me really really much if I can get an answer for this one because i'm really completely stuck and desperate :(

***PS: has it to do something with the: File not found: moc_guiitemlistrepeat.obj ?***

EDIT: in case this can help you here are the

moc_guiitemlistrepeat.obj https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110311126/moc_guiitemlistrepeat.obj

moc_guiitemlistrepeat.cpp https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/110311126/moc_guiitemlistrepeat.cpp

Comment: Have you run `qmake` before building the project?

Comment: @vahancho yes i did in both debug and release, but it does not help.

Comment: @vahancho in case you could use them i added both the moc_'s links in here

Comment: Why `void isUpdated();` declared as a signal, but used as slot?

Comment: Ok that was indeed the problem, i completely forgot i added that there if you add that as answer i will accept it asap, I am really really thankful for this (small in the program but big for me) answer for the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you declare `isUpdated()` function as a signal, however use it as slot in your class. As a result, you got two definitions of the same function: one in `moc_guiitemlistrepeat.cpp` file (generated by qmake), and another is `void GUIItemListRepeat::isUpdated()` definition written by yourself.

To fix the issue you simply need to declare `isUpdated()` as slot.